# Wall colliders for a building

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, blender, virtual-reality

I want to make a VR game using Unity for google cardboard, but I am facing a problem in making wall colliders. I made the game map using blender which is an inside of a building and when ever I make a collider for the building, it won't let me enter it.

Is there a way to make the colliders just for the walls?

Comment: I very find the answer to this question, have you ever had a solution plz ?
I have huge level that will be very hard to convert to multiple box colliders...

Answer (score 1):

You can add **meshColliders** to each of your wall.

Comment: the thing is when I made the walls I linked them all together so its like one long huge wall :( I am thinking of adding a plane and put it inside each wall and then add a collider to each one of them :/ gonna take a lot of time :@

Comment: you can add multiple box colliders and can adjust their size this way you can adjust colliders with your current walls